# Scala compiler _incredibly_ slow on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, compile, scala

I recently tried to install scala and the Scala IDE plugin for Eclipse. Everything's working fine, except for that it takes over 5 seconds to compile a simple hello world program. At first I thought this problem was Eclipse-related, but I tried it in Netbeans and in the comandline, and its slow there too... :(
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different solutions, I tried out the new [Scala IDE](http://www.scala-ide.org/) for Eclipse, which, as far as I know, uses the [Fast Scala Compiler](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/fsc.html) to achieve "awesome" compilation speed (almost as good as with Java), especially compared to NetBeans or compiling on the command line using the regular scala compiler.

Another solution is to use the [Scala Build Tool](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt) which has an option to always recompile in the background, whenever you modify a file. Isn't as fast as Eclipse though, but also has dependency resolution and other fance features.